# Open new tabs with same URL, with different commands in each tab

Tags: html, dom, autohotkey

I need to access a website, then select a cause and hit a button. Because I have multiple variables (causes), I need to do this multiple times, in order to create a report for each one. The url and title of the webpage are the same because the webpage is a form.

So far, I've created this code:

```
WB :=  ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
WB.Visible:=True

wb.Navigate("http://url")
wb.document.title := "cause 1"

WinMaximize, % "ahk_id " wb.HWND
; Wait for page to load:
While wb.Busy or wb.ReadyState != 4
    Sleep, 100

wb.document.getElementsByName("id_cause")[0].value := 1
wb.document.getElementsByName("btnSearch")[0].Click()

wb.Navigate("http://url", 2048)
wb.document.title := "cause 2"


While wb.Busy or wb.ReadyState != 4
    Sleep, 100

wb.document.getElementsByName("id_cause")[0].value := 2
wb.document.getElementsByName("btnSearch")[0].Click()
return
```

As I was expecting, all the commands are referring to the first tab. So, the first tab is renamed cause 1 and after this is renamed again cause 2. 
Searching the web for a solution, I've seen some codes that allow the user to refer to tab, but all of them use URL in order to distinguish the tabs.

Is there a way to achieve my purpose in this scenario (same URLs)? I was thinking about something like tab index or renaming the URLs and use the naming for identification.

One of the codes I've found online is this one:

```
navOpenNewForegroundTab = 65536
navOpenInBackgroundTab = 4096
navOpenInNewWindow = 1
navOpenInNewTab = 2048

wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application") ; create a IE instance
IeHwnd := wb.Hwnd
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("Google.com")
While wb.readyState != 4 || wb.document.readyState != "complete" || wb.busy ; wait for the page to load
   Sleep, 10


wb.Navigate("DuckDuckgo.com", navOpenInNewTab)
while !wb2
    wb2 := New_IE("DuckDuckgo.com")
wb2.Navigate("Google.com")
While wb2.readyState != 4 || wb2.document.readyState != "complete" || wb2.busy ; wait for the page to load
   Sleep, 10


wb.Navigate("DuckDuckgo.com", navOpenInNewTab)
while !wb3
    wb3 := New_IE("DuckDuckgo.com")
wb3.Navigate("Google.com")

While wb3.readyState != 4 || wb3.document.readyState != "complete" || wb3.busy ; wait for the page to load
   Sleep, 10

Msgbox then just use wb or wb2 or wb3 to control tab1, tab2 or tab3`n`nFor Example lets look up something in tab 2 now...

Something_to_look_for := "duckduckgo"
wb2.Navigate("Google.com/#q=" Something_to_look_for)
While wb2.readyState != 4 || wb2.document.readyState != "complete" || wb2.busy ; wait for the page to load
   Sleep, 10
return


New_IE(Url) {
    For wb in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
    {
        If instr( wb.LocationUrl, URL) && InStr( wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe" )
            return wb
        else
            continue
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about the code you found online? Does it work? What is the problem with it?

Comment: It's based on URL but in my case the URL is the same among all tabs so it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

[IEGetN()](https://pastebin.com/9PaLHPSp) is a function that will get you the n-th IE window with the specified title. The window has to be already opened.

You use it like this:

```
 wb1 := IEgetN("Google",1)
 wb5 := IEgetN("Google",5)
```

---

Here is the function:

```
IEGetN(name="",_n=1) 
{
    _counter = 1
    IfEqual, Name,, WinGetTitle, Name, ahk_class IEFrame     ;// Get active window if no parameter
    Name := (Name="New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer")? "about:Tabs":RegExReplace(Name, " - (Windows|Microsoft)? ?Internet Explorer$")
    for wb in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows()
        if wb.LocationName=Name and InStr(wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe")
        {
            if (_counter ==_n)
            {
                return wb 
            }
            _counter += 1
        }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with google.com and I cannot make use of it. The code I've written is here: https://pastebin.com/mu85j263 . As you can see, it should have changed the tab nr. 2 webpage name, but it doesn't. Thanks for the support so far!

Comment: just give the page some time to "breathe"; add `sleep, 2000` before
`wb2 := IEgetN("Google",2)`

Comment: Actually, my tests were failing because the code checks the tabs from all open internet explorer windows, not the active one. Is there a way to limit the  name checking to the current windows?